# Paravirtualizing linux on an ARM platform

Tags: linux, linux-kernel, arm

I want to learn how to port linux to an ARM platform, and I am wondering if you guys have any tips or resources on how to do that? Everything from writing the boot file to setting up the interrupt vector, writing the linker script and having the executable system running.

I was thinking of buying a developer board to learn this, maybe Beagle board as it uses an ARM cortex processor and has a big user community. Is this a good idea? I am not very familiar with linux or porting operating systems in general, so any tips on how to get started would be nice!

What I want to do in the end is to virtualize all the linux kernels privileged operations to run in a hypervisor. Currently I have a hypervisor that is run beneath freeRTOS. All freeRTOS privileged operations (very few operations) have been changed to trap into the hypervisor by generating a SWI interrupt which leads to the hypervisor. What I want to do is too extend it to Linux instead which is more complex and alot bigger.

Best regards

Mr Gigu

Comment: This should either go to serverfault or http://unix.stackexchange.com

Comment: Not really, this sounds like kernel development to me

Comment: have a look at linaro which is linux on arm http://www.linaro.org/ BeagleBoard sounds like an excellent idea to me!

Comment: What's the point of a hypervisor when you already have an OS?  Shouldn't that stuff be handled/modified there?

Comment: As the thin hypervisor is only around 1-2k lines of code it's easy to do a formal verification of its isolation of different execution environments. The idea is to run the hypervisor at the most privileged ring, while having the kernel and it's applications on a less privileged ring. This way whenever we want to use a privileged operation on the kernel, it traps to the hypervisor and it will perform that operation. As regular OS contains several millions line of code, its impossible to do a formal verification on the OS. Main idea is to isolate trusted applications from "regular" apps.

Comment: @MrGigu: Just because an OS consists of millions of lines of code, doesn't mean the kernel has to.  Microkernel OSes have been well-known and used where verification is important for a long time now, for example QNX, used for avionics and life-support devices.

Comment: This is a very large project if you are unfamiliar with kernel programming - you may want to find a smaller sub-project in this project and start with, just to see if you like this kind of work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would say start here...

http://elinux.org/BeagleBoard

From what I have seen, the Beagle Board seems to be one of the most widely supported boards 'community-wise' at this level.

As far as your questions goes, I am not totally sure what it is. If you are diving into all this embedded OS and linux stuff and want to have fun, that board is the probably way to go if you have some background with embedded development (which it seems you do).  As far as professional development, not so sure...

Comment: What do you recommend for professional development? I am almost finished with my master thesis which is "implementing security services in a thin hypervisor in embedded systems". The reason I'm doing this is that I want to learn more about embedded systems, I want to prepare myself for working with this professionaly!

Comment: Never seen anything about a 'thin hypervisor' in the embedded world really.  Not sure how common or practical they are outside of theory/academics at the moment.  But professionally the processor you choose will be dependent on the industry you target and the needs of the application.  So if you are just doing this for yourself, it's not really a big deal since most ARM based platforms are pretty easy to port amongst.

Answer (score 3):

You might want to check out the way it's done in [L4Linux](http://l4linux.org/).

Comment: +1 for actually answering the question.  OKL4 has a commercial package, although version 3 was GPL and is still available.  They are base on the L4 micro-kernel API.  I think `TrustZone` changes the game.  Don't believe the **hype** about performance.  Interrupt latencies are horrible on systems that use the MMU alone to provide system partitioning.